# Is a+5 is valid expression in C , where a is an array?

Tags: c

So `a[10]` is an `int` array. The question is, whether only `(a+5)` is valid. If it was accessed through pointer [ex: `*(a+5)`] then it should be valid. Is this valid without pointer?

Comment: Depends. What do you want to _access_, value or address?

Comment: What do you mean with "valid"? Valid in the program's domain, or valid in C?

Comment: __Declaration__, no. However `a+5` can be a part of a __Statement__

Comment: is that declaration valid to access values?

Comment: a Declaration is the part of the code where the variables are declared. e.g. `int a[10]`. A Statement is the part where actual operations take place. e,g `a[5] = 10` `*(a+5) = 10` `(a+5) = 23333`

Comment: @Rishi; *However `a+5 `can be a part of a Statement*: only as rvalue.

Comment: @haccks - you are right. The last one should be 'ptr = (a+5)`

Comment: @Rishi now you are being deliberately confusing.

Answer (score 3):

`(a + 5)` is equivalent to `&a[5]`. When you use an array name as an R-value in an expression, it gets converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. And when you add `n` to a pointer, it increments it to the address of the `n`th element in the array that the pointer points to. So as long as `n` is less than the array size, the expression is valid. Also, `a + size` is valid, but you must not indirect through it; it's mainly allowed so you can keep incrementing the pointer in a loop until it goes outside the array, and you can test whether it has reached that point.

Note that C has no automatic bounds checking. If you calculate an invalid pointer, like a+20, you're not guaranteed to get an error. This is undefined behavior in C, and anything can happen, including silence. If you read from it, you'll likely get some garbage, but you could also get a segmentation fault. If you write through it, you may corrupt some other variable, and the results can be very unpredictable.

Comment: What do you mean with "you can't indirect through it" ?

Comment: You can use `*(a + size + 1)` because there's no element there to access.

Comment: I'd say you can, it will just lead to undefined behaviour. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I made a mistake, I meant `(a + size)`.

Comment: That's what I meant, you can't validly indirect through it, because it's undefined.

Comment: But there is no way you can use it to test whether you are out of bounds. Your program might crash at best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98880/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-barmar).

Comment: You're allowed to do `if (p < a + 10)`

Answer (score 2):

If `a[10]` is declared, both `a+5` and `*(a+5)` are valid C.

`a+5` is a pointer to an integer, `*(a+5)` is the value that pointer points to (an integer).

Example:

```
int a[10];
a[5] = 100;

printf("%d; %d\n", a[5], *(a+5));    // output: 100; 100
printf("%p; %p\n", &a[5], a+5);      // output: two identical addresses
```

Comment: Technically `printf("%p; %p\n", &a[5], a+5);` should be `printf("%p; %p\n", (void *)&a[5], (void *)(a+5));`.

Comment: "output: two identical pointers"; perhaps "output: two identical **memory addresses**" would be more correct? The pointer is the variable that holds the address, and the address is its value (what gets printed in this case). Maybe a bit lawyer-y, I know...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not pointers. An array is a non modifiable l-value. `(a+5)` will evaluate to rvalue and can only be use as rvalue.
If `a` would be a pointer still `(a+5)` can't be used as an lvalue because the result of `+` operator is a rvalue.

Comment: (a+5) can still be used as an rvalue. e.g. `int *ptr = (a+5)`